Sharepoint List Auto Incrementing ID based off other Column Groups
So I have a SharePoint List that clients need to fill out.
I need a column that autopopulates an incrementing ID for each Program Office.
I attached an image of how it should look. Can I do this as a caluclated column? I see alot of stuff to do a Power Automate, which i never used. But with instructions im sure i can follow easily. Thanks for the help! :)


Here is a simple Power Automate that might work for your scenario.
Assumptions

Incrementing ID will be 4-char long padded with leading zeros (0s).
This can be adjusted by initializing a string variable in Power Automate
with the required length
The existing IncrementingID values will not be changed manually.

Power Automate Logic

Create an Automated Power Automate When an item is created

Initialize a string variable with only zeros like 0000

Get the latest IncrementingID for the ProgramOffice that the item has
been created for. Use ODATA Query - see expressions below

If a previous IncrementingID exists, extract number part and increment
by 1. Otherwise, the IncrementingID will be the first for that
ProgamOffice and will start with 1 like 0001

Using Power Automate expressions, format the new IncrementingID

Update the item in the SharePoint list with the newly created
IncrementingID


Power Automate Actions and Expressions

Detail-1

Detail-2

Detail-3

first(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'])?['IncrementingID']
Detail-4

length(trim(string(outputs('PrevIncrementalID'))))
add(int(trim(replace(string(outputs('PrevIncrementalID')), '0',''))),1)
concat(variables('varNewNumber'), string(outputs('NewIntID')))
substring(outputs('ConcatInitial_and_newInt'), length(string(outputs('NewIntID'))))
Detail-5

Final Output


Thank you so much! I’m trying to following along with this. I’m getting g an error message “Unable to process template language expressions in action ‘NewIntID’ inputs at line ‘0’ and column ‘0’. The template language function ‘Int’ was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.’

Could you check value of PrevIncrementalID? It must be empty or a valid int value for [NewIntID] step to work. Before Condition step, you could use compose to output PrevIncrementalID. The error message is on this statement, add(int(trim(replace(string(outputs('PrevIncrementalID')), '0',''))),1)

Not really understanding. What do you mean by check the value? It’s the formula you said to put. first(outputs(‘Get_items’)?[‘body/value’])?[SequenceNumber’]. That’s my column name, Sequence Number.

At what step are you getting this error? Based on what you've shared, int() function can't convert a string value into an integer value to increment by 1.  So, wondering what you have in PrevIncrementalID column? Make sure it has 1) Empty/Null 2) an integer with padding 0s like 0004

Also, first review the steps and expressions I've shared and let me know if you have any questions for me.

The error is at the 'NewIntID' part. I have reviewed the steps and expressions, it all matches right. Is this something in my SharePoint List not right? I have the Sequence Number column set up as a number column. I tried putting in a form and left the sequence number empty then tried with the flow and its giving the same error. Thanks for your help, clearly im a dumb dumb lol sorry

In my example list [IncrementalId],
I've renamed [Title] to [ProgramOffice], which is a [Single line of text] column, and created
[IncrementingID] column as a [Single line of text]. I would recommend creating a brand new list exactly the same as the sample and try it again
Please note that the Power Automate will trigger [When an item is created]
Let me know if you need any further help.

My program office is and needs to be a drop down menu of choices. And I just created a new column for it instead of replacing title. So under get items filter Query I put ProgramOffice eq ‘Program Office Value’ and ID ne ID

Essentially the client will fill out a form for a new request and the Program Office will be a drop down of choices. I need power automate to look at whatever office was selected and increment the sequence number by 1 for that office. In the format 0001.

I just don’t get a lot of the back end stuff or what these formulas are doing so it’s hard for me to relate it to my list. Apologies and thanks again for the further help
